# Solving 2nd order differential equation with boundary condition z(inf) = 0

Tags: matlab, ode, differential-equations

How can I solve a 2<sup>nd</sup> order differential equation with boundary condition like `z(inf)`?

```
2(x+0.1)·z'' + 2.355·z' - 0.71·z = 0
z(0) = 1
z(inf) = 0
z'(0) = -4.805
```

I can't understand where the boundary value `z(inf)` is to be used in `ode45()` function.
I used in the following condition  `[z(0) z'(0) z(inf)]`, but this does not give accurate output.

```
function [T, Y]=test()

    % some random x function 
    x = @(t) t;

    t=[0 :.01 :7];


    % integrate numerically
    [T, Y] = ode45(@linearized, t, [1 -4.805 0]);

    % plot the result
    plot(T, Y(:,1))

    % linearized ode
    function dy = linearized(t,y)

       dy = zeros(3,1);
       dy(1) = y(2);
       dy(2) = y(3);
       dy(3) = (-2.355*y(2)+0.71*y(1))/((2*x(t))+0.2);

    end

end
```

please help me to solve this differential equation.

Comment: Thank u @Rody for your invaluable correction

Comment: I suspect you have simply misunderstood something -- a *second*-order ODE with *three* initial values is overconstrained and can generally not be solved. I suspect the `z(inf)` condition is to be used in the choice of `x`; e.g. if you choose `x = 0.9879·t` (roughly), then `z(t) ⇒ 0` for `t ⇒ ∞`. So could you elaborate a bit where this equation and its initial values comes from?

Answer (score 1):

You seem to have a fairly advanced problem on your hands, but very limited knowledge of MATLAB and/or ODE theory. I'm happy to explain more if you want, but that should be in chat (I'll invite you) or via personal e-mail (my last name AT the most popular mail service from Google DOT com)

Now that you've clarified a few things and explained the *whole* problem, things are a bit more clear and I was able to come up with a reasonable solution. I think the following is at least in the general direction of what you'd need to do:

```
function  [tSpan, Y2, Y3] = test

    %%# Parameters

    %# Time parameters
    tMax  = 1e3;
    tSpan = 0 : 0.01 : 7;

    %# Initial values
    y02 = [1 -4.805];    %# second-order ODE
    y03 = [0 0 4.8403];  %# third-order ODE

    %# Optimization options
    opts = optimset(...
        'display', 'off',...
        'TolFun' , 1e-5,...
        'TolX'   , 1e-5);


    %%# Main procedure

    %# Find X so that z2(t,X) -> 0 for t -> inf
    sol2 = fminsearch(@obj2, 0.9879680932400429, opts);

    %# Plug this solution into the original
    %# NOTE: we need dense output, which is done via deval()
    Z = ode45(@(t,y) linearized2(t,y,sol2), [0 tMax], y02);

    %# plot the result
    Y2 = deval(Z,tSpan,1);
    plot(tSpan, Y2, 'b');


    %# Find X so that z3(t,X) -> 1 for t -> inf
    sol3 = fminsearch(@obj3, 1.215435887288112, opts);

    %# Plug this solution into the original
    [~, Y3] = ode45(@(t,y) linearized3(t,y,sol3), tSpan, y03);

    %# plot the result
    hold on, plot(tSpan, Y3(:,1), 'r');

    %# Finish plots
    legend('Second order ODE', 'Third order ODE')
    xlabel('T [s]')
    ylabel('Function value [-]');

    %%# Helper functions

    %# Function to optimize X for the second-order ODE
    function val = obj2(X)
        [~, y] = ode45(@(t,y) linearized2(t,y,X), [0 tMax], y02);
        val = abs(y(end,1));
    end

    %# linearized second-order ODE with parameter X
    function dy = linearized2(t,y,X)
        dy = [
            y(2)
            (-2.355*y(2) + 0.71*y(1))/2/(X*t + 0.1)
            ];
    end


    %# Function to optimize X for the third-order ODE
    function val = obj3(X3)
        [~, y] = ode45(@(t,y) linearized3(t,y,X3), [0 tMax], y03);
        val = abs(y(end,2) - 1);
    end

    %# linearized third-order ODE with parameters X and Z
    function dy = linearized3(t,y,X)
        zt = deval(Z, t, 1);
        dy = [
            y(2)
            y(3)
            (-1 -0.1*zt + y(2) -2.5*y(3))/2/(X*t + 0.1)
            ];
    end

end
```

Answer (score 0):

As in my comment above, I *think* you're confusing a couple of things. I suspect this is what is requested:

```
function [T,Y] = test

    tMax = 1e3;

    function val = obj(X)
        [~, y] = ode45(@(t,y) linearized(t,y,X), [0 tMax], [1 -4.805]);
        val = abs(y(end,1));
    end

    % linearized ode with parameter X
    function dy = linearized(t,y,X)
        dy = [
            y(2)
            (-2.355*y(2) + 0.71*y(1))/2/(X*t + 0.1)
            ];
    end

    % Find X so that z(t,X) -> 0 for t -> inf
    sol = fminsearch(@obj, 0.9879);

    % Plug this ssolution into the original 
    [T, Y] = ode45(@(t,y) linearized(t,y,sol), [0 tMax], [1 -4.805]);

    % plot the result
    plot(T, Y(:,1));

end
```

but I can't get it to converge anymore for `tMax` beyond 1000 seconds. You may be running into the limits of `ode45` capabilities w.r.t. accuracy (switch to `ode113`), or your initial value is not accurate enough, etc.

Comment: your code works well and gives correct result as it matchs the desired curve. In next phase i have to solve a third other differetial equation. 2(x+.1)·y''' + 2.5.y'' +1 -y'+ 0·1.z = 0

Comment: @user3637659: OK; can you solve that with what I showed you? So in general, an initial value problem with an *N* th order ODE has exactly *N* initial values. If it has less initial values, it is a family of solutions; if it has more initial values, it's only possible to solve it if there are more variables to play with (for example, your `x`).

Comment: How can i handle the y'(inf)=1 condition from here 2(x+.1)·y''' + 2.5.y'' +1 -y'+ 0·1.z = 0; y(0)=0,y'(0)=0,y'(inf)=1, y''(0)=4.8403. Here the z value come from the Y(:,1) of previous 2nd order solution